# Change foreach loop output from latest to oldest

Tags: php, foreach

Now  i'm getting data from my database and than put it inside my foreach loop but it want it to show the latest row first

For example database row is 
First: Hello
Second: Hi
Third: HAI!

So i want it to start outputting with HAI end with Hello.

Code;

```
    foreach($message_show as $b){
        $deliver = $b['deliver'];
        $source = $b['source'];
        $message_date = $b['message_date'];
        $message_time = $b['message_time'];
        echo "<div id=message-board>
                <div class=message-head>
                    <span class=verzender><a href=1.php?id=$deliver>$deliver</a></span> 
                    <span class=bericht-datum-tijd>
                        <span class=bericht-datum>$message_date</span> 
                        <span class=bericht-tijd>$message_time</span>
                    </span>
                </div> 
                <span class=bericht>$source</span>
                ";  
        if($isOwner == $id OR $isOwner == $deliver OR $isAdmin){
            echo '
                <form id=delete-form method=POST>
                    <input type="hidden" name="message-del" value="'. $b["id"]. '">
                    <button name=message-delete>x Verwijderen</button>
                </form>
            ';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

Comment: Just change the sort order in your query... e.g. `ORDER BY message_date DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the **ORDER BY id DESC** for sorting out newest to oldest data.

Note: "id" should be primary key of the table in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $message_show is your array filled with database query, you must execute this, before foreach

```
krsort($message_show);
```